# GCC compile error with virtual function

Tags: c++, gcc, abstract-class

I got a weird error when compiling my simple C++ program with GCC, here is the detail:

I have an abstract class called `ware`, it has 1 *virtual function* called `run()`, and the `router` class implement this abstract class. I compile them with `make` and I got a strange error. Let's see all the code below:

**ware.h**

```cc
class ware {
public:
   virtual void run() = 0;
};
```

**router.h**

```cc
#include "ware.h"

class router: ware {
public:
    void run();
};
```

**router.cc**

```cc
#include "router.h"

void router::run() {
    // do something
}
```

And here is my `makefile`

```
all: clean build

build:
  gcc router.cc main.cc -o main

clean:
  rm -rf main
```

When I try to compile, I got this error:

```
gcc router.cc main.cc -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for ware in router-da2a57.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for router in router-da2a57.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me check this out and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Am I make any mistake when configuring GCC in my `makefile`?

Thank you so much :(

Comment: Try `g++` instead of `gcc`

Comment: use `g++` for compiling C++ code. It's not linking the c++ runtime.